# Load subdomain from folder with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I have a project setup where I have multiple subdomains for different purposes like `login.example.com`, `signup.example.com` and `blog.example.com`. I only have the domain configured but not created any sub-domains. All sub-domains should be loaded from their respective folder on root folder like `example.com` is running from root folder files and there are 3 more folders for `login`, `signup` and `blog`.

I have written this code in `.htaccess` file to load sub-domain from folder

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^login.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/login/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

But it's not working and giving me a 500 error.

How can I do it?

Comment: A 500 error is the webservers way of saying "I have a major problem, but I don't want to talk about it in public". Look at the error log of the server, there will be a clear message saying what's wrong.

Comment: Those directives shouldn't be giving a 500 error, unless perhaps mod_rewrite is not enabled on your server?